# How can i get list of Domain user's from Google Apps account?

Tags: c#

I am using Google API Ver 2 for .NET.
I want to access list of domains users with there information like **userid and password**.

How can display list domain user's using Admin's credential?

Thanx

Answer (score 3):

Use the `RetrieveAllUsers()` method as described here: http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference_dotnet.html#Retrieve_All_Users_in_Domain_Example

To create the service object and authenticate with your admin account, see this code sample:

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference_dotnet.html#Authenticating_To_Your_Domain

Comment: thanx Jonas.

I am getting list of all users but unable to fetch 'password' field of domain user.

Can you help me out here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's omitted for security reasons.

Comment: Password is never returned in API calls. It can only be set or updated. http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html#google_apps_tag_apps:login