# How can i get list of domain users from Google Apps account without administrative access?

Tags: google-api

This is a similar question to [How can i get list of Domain user's from Google Apps account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704482/how-can-i-get-list-of-domain-users-from-google-apps-account)

However, I'd like to use a normal account (not an administrative account) to retrieve the user list.  It seems like this should be possible as the gmail autocomplete returns domain contacts  not listed in the user's contact store.  I've looked at the autocomplete Ajax call, but it requires something in the beginning of the string (and no, I don't really want to loop through a-z one by one - that is just way to hacky).  For example:

> https://mail.google.com/mail/c/u/0/data/contactstore?ac=true&ct=true&gp=true&hl=en&id=domain&max=15&out=js&tok=*beginningOfUsersName*&type=4

Both versions of the Google contacts API seem to omit domain users unless you have them imported into your own contacts list.  I've also looked at querying users in the "Coworkers" [system group](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/docs/3.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#System_groups), all to no avail.  I also find it interesting that "add a coworker's calendar" on Google calendar does **not** provide autocomplete - they use a popup instead.

I'm working on a C# project, but this is a general Google API question, so any pointers in any language would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

It looks like this is feasible now with admin/directory google api endpoints
see: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users?authuser=0#retrieve_users_non_admin

**Original answer**

I was able to work around this issue, so I'll document the workaround, even if it doesn't involve Google.  I wrote a program (in C#) to query the internal Active Directory (LDAP) store and pick up all the users from there instead.  At that point I could get their email addresses and query Google with it.  Not the best method, but it worked for my needs.

The C# was roughly patterned from this powershell script, although I pulled out the computers query and added in the capture of the user's email address:  http://www.visualbasicscript.com/List-all-users-or-computers-in-the-default-domain-m35650.aspx

The LDAP property I included to get the proper email address for Google was 'proxyAddresses', although this will not be correct for all environments.